# HTML5 drop event has a different e.target to scope

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create an HTML5 drag and drop implementation using the following pattern.

```
<table>
  <tr draggable=true>
    <td>hello world 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr draggable=true>
    <td>hello world 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>


var ReorderStories = function() {
};

ReorderStories.prototype = {

  addEvents : function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('dragenter', this, false);
    el.addEventListener('dragover', this, false);
    el.addEventListener('dragleave', this, false);
    el.addEventListener('drop', this, false);
    el.addEventListener('dragend', this, false);

    return el;
  },

  handleEvent : function(e) {

    switch(e.type) {
      case "dragstart": this.handleDragStart(e); break;
      case "dragenter": this.handleDragEnter(e); break;
      case "dragover": this.handleDragOver(e); break;
      case "dragleave": this.handleDragLeave(e); break;
      case "drop": this.handleDrop(e); break;
      case "dragend": this.handleDragEnd(e); break;
    }
  },

  handleDrop : function(e) {
    console.log(this, e.target);
  }
}
```

Using this pattern I can maintain the scope of the class in the drop handler which is great because I can reference all the other properties and functions of that class. However, it turns out that e.target does not expose the same dom object as "this" would in the following example:

```
el.addEventListener('drop', function(){ 
  console.log(this, e.target)
}, false);
```

In fact in the above example this and e.target would be different dom objects altogether, where "this" would be the draggable object (tr) and e.target would be the td element.

Is there a sensible way to structure this class to get around this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you want, but `e.target` is a subject to bubbling propagation. See [other event target options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets), especially `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: Hi @katspaugh, I appreciate e.target is subject to bubbling. e.currentTarget will actualy give the same result as e.target in this case. My point is that the event object never seems to expose the draggable target that you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem you are facing is that e.target is always coming up as the innermost element that is being dropped on rather than the element the event was attached to (`el`).

The most logical approach (to me) would be to have exactly one instance of ReorderStories per element.  You could do something like this:

```
var ReorderStories = function(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this.addEvents(el);
};
```

In this case, on all your events, `this` would refer to the instance of `ReorderStories` and `this.el` would refer to the element you attached the event to.